# Dynamic DNS in packet tunnel provider IOS

Tags: swift, dns, vpn, tunnel, networkextension

i have app contain vpn configuration using packet tunnel provider
on setting of the tunnel on  tunnelNetworkSettings.dnsSettings we put 8.8.8.8
there is any elegant and legal way to change it to be dynamic by the dns the device use (wifi,4g etc...)

let dnsSettings = NEDNSSettings(servers:[8.8.8.8])

tunnelNetworkSettings.dnsSettings = dnsSettings

Comment: You device may use local router as DNS forwarder so my guess that those IPs won't work inside the tunnel and you have to provide something accessible over the tunnel. My best guess you can try implementing `NEDNSProxyProvider` alongside packet tunnel and help route DNS traffic the way you see it fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the System DNS server by using the this code

```
static func getSystemDnsList() -> ([String]/*IPV4*/, [String]/*IPV6*/) {
        var dnsListIPV4 = [String]()
        var dnsListIPV6 = [String]()
            let structSize = MemoryLayout<__res_9_state>.size
            let res = UnsafeMutablePointer<__res_9_state>.allocate(capacity: structSize)
            let result = res_9_ninit(res)
            if result == 0 {
                let structSize = MemoryLayout<res_9_sockaddr_union>.size
                let capacity = Int(res.pointee.nscount) * structSize

                let addrUnion = UnsafeMutablePointer<res_9_sockaddr_union>.allocate(capacity: capacity)
                res_9_getservers(res, addrUnion, res.pointee.nscount)

                for i in 0..<Int(res.pointee.nscount) {
                    if addrUnion[i].sin.sin_family == AF_INET {
                        let ip = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity: Int(INET_ADDRSTRLEN))

                        var ipStringObject : String?
                        if let ipStr = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(addrUnion[i].sin.sin_addr), ip, socklen_t(INET_ADDRSTRLEN)) {
                            ipStringObject = String(utf8String: ipStr)
                        }

                        var portStringObject : String?
                        let port = nTohs(addrUnion[i].sin.sin_port)
                        portStringObject = String(format: "%d", port)

                        if let ip = ipStringObject {
                            dnsListIPV4.append(ip)
                        }
                    } else if addrUnion[i].sin6.sin6_family == AF_INET6 {
                        let ip = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity: Int(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN))

                        var ipStringObject : String?
                        if let ipStr = inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(addrUnion[i].sin6.sin6_addr), ip, socklen_t(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN)) {
                            ipStringObject = String(utf8String: ipStr)
                        }

                        var portStringObject : String?
                        let port = nTohs(addrUnion[i].sin6.sin6_port)
                        portStringObject = String(format: "%d", port)

                        if let ip = ipStringObject {
                            dnsListIPV6.append(ip)
                        }
                    }
                }

                res_9_nclose(res)
                free(res)
            }

            return (dnsListIPV4, dnsListIPV6)
        }
```